# create integer associated to a string in java

Tags: string, object, integer

i've been programming for about three weeks on a game in Java.
The last days I was searching for a way to "connect" an integer value to an string and being abled to create new objects which are abled to hold this values aswell. 
This would be needed to create item-objects holding an item-ID and the path for the item-image.

I got some inspiration from other people in my company aswell, who told me to use XML-Files or CSV-files to save the item-ID to the correct item-path, but before i learn to create an XML or use a CSV i wanted to know if there might be a better or easier way to create items without wasting more time in try and error to assign an Integer to an String...

Thanks for your Attention

Comment: if the values dont have to present after closing your game, I suggest you look into HasTables: https://beginnersbook.com/2014/07/hashtable-in-java-with-example/

Comment: Use HashMap instead because in your case String can be null but Hash Table doesn't allow null values and it also provides Key-Value pair like Hash Table.

Comment: Thank you for the quick help! :D 
i already tried the HashTables and were a little disapointed because i planned an array for the inventory to insert a item-ID and test for the number in the itemlist, but i can't assign an integer in the HashTable. 
Is this also a problem in the HashMap? 
If it is, should i try to cast the values or go for something else?